# How to create a bottom toggle bar?

Tags: jquery, css

I have created this drawer but I don't know how to move it in the bottom-right corner and when you open it the content to come from bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/d150x4w1/

```
html {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  background-color: #a11544;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  float: right;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 25px 25px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 25px 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px 25px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.drawer-inside {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .4s ease;
  background: #c3c3c3;
}
.drawer-inside.openup {
  height: 210px;
  transition: height .7s ease;
}
```

Comment: switch the order of the toggle with the content around, and it should come from the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the button to the top (*in the html*)

Add the following css rules

```
.drawer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
}
.drawer-appear{clear:both;}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/j5xoe8xg/

Answer (score 1):

just try the following and add it to the .button:

```
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
```

And the following to .drawer:

```
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
position:fixed; }
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: it is moving the button but when you click the content is showing on top as well

Comment: Add position and bottom to .drawer inside too.

Comment: and now is not moving the drawer

Comment: The content box should appear from the bottom if you click on the button, right?  I tested it with .drawer-inside and .drawer as well. Just try this:
    .drawer {
        bottom:0px;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
    }

Comment: Well, maybe I missunderstood you, but what is the problem now? The button is in the bottom-right corner and the content appears from the bottom? Or should the drawer appear from the bottom-right corner as well?

Comment: Well I want as my button to move in same time with the content

Comment: Whould should happen with the button if the drawer appears? More information please.

Comment: Well before when the button was on top, the button was moved to down with the content. Now if is on bottom it should to be moved with content in top

Comment: Now I understand: add overflow:hidden; to .button

Comment: have you checked this? I can't see any changing